# VB Script CSTR alternative in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, vbscript

CStr in VB script throws error when NULL value is passed to it, whereas CStr in VB.NET ignores null value and doesn't throw error.

Is there any other function which does same function as CStr in VB script.

```
 Try
     Dim str As String
     str = Nothing
     'assuming above line will set str to null.

     Dim x As String

     x = CStr(str)

     ' I am expecting CStr above should throw exception as it does in VBScript.
   Catch ex As Exception

  End Try
```

Thanks and Regards,
PV

Comment: Please show that code  where you are assigning null.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) in order to get a string representation of an object.

This is invoked on the object itself:

```
MyVariable.ToString()
```

Note that for many objects this will return the type of the object - you need to give more details regarding what exactly you are trying to do and with what objects.

Comment: will i get exception when i pass NULL to ToString() function?

Comment: @sqlnewbie - That's not how it works. But if you try to invoke it on a variable that is set to `null` (`Nothing` in VB.NET) you will get an exception.

Comment: @HansPassant - That's what he wants. A VB.NET alternative to the vbscript `CStr`.

Comment: ToString() works partially as it throws object reference exception when I call ToString() on string which has NULL value.

Comment: However if we can have some function which throws a pretty decent error then it would be great, VB script throws an error saying cannot pass NULL to CStr function.

Comment: @sqlnewbie - Look at the type of the excpetion. It is a `NullReferenceException`. It means that you have tried to invoke a member on a `null` object.